# BookhshelfJS: Attaching One-to-One relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, relational-database, bookshelf.js

I have two tables, `User` and `Address`. My table `User` has two methods:

```
shippingAddress: function() {
    var Address = require(appRoot + '/config/db').model('Address');
    return this.belongsTo(Address, 'shipping_address_id');
},

billingAddress: function() {
    var Address = require(appRoot + '/config/db').model('Address');
    return this.belongsTo(Address, 'billing_address_id');
}
```

How can I attach an `Address` to say my `shippingAddress`? I tried the following:

```
new Address(addressQuery)
    .fetch()
    .then(function (address) {
        new User(userQuery)
            .fetch()
            .then(function (user) {
                // Nothing here works
                // I tried the following:
                user.shippingAddress().attach(address); // Attach is not defined
                user.shippingAddress().sync(address);   // Nothing happens
                user.shippingAddress().set(address);    // Nothing happens
                user.save();
            });
    });
```

The only thing I can do is:

```
user.attributes.shipping_address_id = address.id;
user.save();
```

Which is not a very elegant solution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set the list of relations with "withRelated"

```
new User(userQuery)
        .fetch({
            withRelated:['shippingAddress']
        })
        .then(function (user) {
```

Then you're able to do:

```
user.related('shippingAddress').set(...).save();
```

Be sure shippingAddress() isn't a 'static' function within your User model